# Rails rest put HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I need to use RESTful input to my Rails app.  First I'm trying to just understand REST and I'm using WizTools RestClient on my MAC for testing.

I have a table called priorities and I'm trying to update a field called prioritydesc.

This is the info I'm using

```
METHOD = PUT
URL = http://mywebsite/priorities/4
HEADER = prioritydesc
VALUE = "TEST"
```

The results I'm getting is:

```
HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented
```

If I use the resttesttest.com site, I get:

Origin http://resttesttest.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1:

Do I need gem "oauth-plugin"?

UDPATE2:

This is my priorities_controller PUT:

```
 # PUT /priorities/1
 # PUT /priorities/1.json
def update
 @priority = Priority.find(params[:id])

 respond_to do |format|
   if @priority.update_attributes(params[:priority])
     format.html { redirect_to @priority, notice: 'Priority was successfully updated.' }
     format.json { head :ok }
   else
     format.html { render action: "edit" }
     format.json { render json: @priority.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

UPDATE3

I tried on localhost using:

```
METHOD = PUT
URL = http://localhost/priorities/1
HEADER = prioritynum
VALUE = 5
```

And got

```
"<html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:5000/priorities/4">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
```

That seems OK to me.

But, the value didn't update.

UPDATE4

I used this:

```
METHOD = POST
URL = http://localhost/priorities
HEADER = prioritynum
VALUE = 5
```

And it added a new record!  But, the prioritynum was blank

I also tried using

```
http://localhost:5000/priorities?prioritynum=5
```

Should the data field(s) like (prioritynum=5) be in the header or the body?
I put this in the body and it didn't work:

```
typecode="test"
```

UPDATE5

OK this worked !!

```
 METHOD = PUT
 URL = http://mywebsite/priorities?priority[prioritynum]=5
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `PrioritiesController` class?  Or at least the update method.

Comment: And you have `resources :priorities` in your routes.rb?

Comment: I have   `resources :priorities` in my routes.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working for the types controller - I used this:

```
Method = POST
URL =  http://mywesite/types?type[typecode]=test&type[typedesc]=test%20description
```